# Is there an integer random access iterator in standard lib or boost?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, c++17

I try to find a turnkey iterator over integers, which supports all operations of [`boost::counting_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html), but also supports increment and decrement by a number (`Iter operator+(Integer num);`); Is there a simple way to make it without writing myself (for example, a base in boost which takes tags and provides a ready-to-use random access integer iterator)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is using the `iterator_facade` to ease implementing one enough?

```
struct Seq : boost::iterator_facade<Seq, int, boost::random_access_traversal_tag, int> {
    Seq(int initial = 0) : _val(initial) {}

    bool      equal(Seq rhs) const              { return _val == rhs._val; } 
    int       dereference() const               { return _val;             } 
    ptrdiff_t distance_to(Seq const& rhs) const { return rhs._val - _val;  } 
    void      advance(ptrdiff_t n)              { _val += n;               } 
    void      decrement()                       { --_val;                  } 
    void      increment()                       { ++_val;                  } 

  private:
    int _val;
};
```

See **[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9633adc08817870)**

```
for (Seq it(100), e(197); it <= e; it += 13) {
    std::cout << *it << " " << std::flush;
}
```

Prints

```
100 113 126 139 152 165 178 191
```

Comment: After doing some experiments with boost concepts (BOOST_CONCEPT_CHECK + RandomAccessRangeConcept), I can add that there should also be such functions as `equal`, `increment` and `decrement`. It is also useful to add std::iterator_traits<Seq>.

Comment: @ГеоргийГуминов Thanks, updated the code to include those members. I'll leave iterator traits (boost's traits already work)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is impossible.

`counted_iterator` is intended to mirror the functionality of the iterator it is given. But it can only work with what it is given. If you give it a random-access iterator, it will mirror that functionality.

If you give it a forward iterator and then allow the user to increment it with any integer, you are *lying* to the user. Random access iterator incrementing means more than that you can call `operator+` with an integer. It means that this operation has O(1) complexity. And if the underlying iterator doesn't have that complexity on its iteration advancement... you cannot *manufacture* it from outside of the iterator.

Well, you could by heap-allocating an array of iterators of the size determined by the range you're given. But that's a really bad idea.

If you want to increment an iterator a bunch, but you don't know that the iterator is random-access, use `std::next` or `std::advance`.