# Binary search over function results in C++

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, binary-search, std-ranges

I am looking for a way to do a binary search over function results with a signature close to the following:

```
template <class ArgT,
          class ResultT,
          class TransformFunc,
          class Compare = std::less<ResultT>>
ArgT
result_upper_bound(ResultT searched, ArgT begin, ArgT end, TransformFunc tf, Compare comp);
```

The function is expected to return a first arg in the range [begin, end) which gives `TransformFunc` result that does not satisfy `result` > `searched`.

I have succeded in doing this task by implementing [iterator over integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74805695/is-there-an-integer-random-access-iterator-in-standard-lib-or-boost) and using `std::ranges::views::transform` and `std::ranges::upper_bound`. The problim is that this solution does not work with `clang` becuse `ranges` library is not correctly supported by this compiler and will not be until `clang 16` is released. By the way, the code is close to this:

```
...
auto argsRng = std::ranges::subrange<MyIntIt<uint64_t>>(
    MyIntIt<uint64_t>(0), MyIntIt<uint64_t>(Conditions::bigNumber));
const auto func = [](uint64_t index) {
    return Conditions::func(index);
};
auto transformed =
    std::ranges::views::transform(argsRng, func);
auto it = std::ranges::upper_bound(transformed, searchedArg);
...
```

`boost::transform_iterator` and `boost::range::adaptors::transform` are not exactly RandomAccess. That means their usage instead of `std::ranges::views::transform` makes `std::lower_bound` non-effective.

What are other ways of implementing this without writing binary search?

Comment: This is just a minor variation on `std::upper_bound`. If this is a homework assignment, then it's a safe bet that the student is expected to manually implement the algorithm directly, instead of using C++20 ranges, or other library resources.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik , it is not a homework assignment.

Comment: Your `TransformFunc` looks to me like a projection function, which is already supported by the C++20 constrained algorithms. So I don't think you need to implement `result_upper_bound` in C++20, just call `ranges::upper_bound` with the appropriate arguments should be enough.

Comment: @康桓瑋 , TransformFunc is user defined function, it is an argument.

Comment: @ГеоргийГуминов The projection function is a user-defined function, which is also the fourth argument of [`ranges::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/upper_bound).

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't solve random coding puzzles from scam sites.

Comment: Ah yes, projection, one of the cool things about ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution both compiles in `clang++14` and `gcc-12`:

```
...
using IntIter = IntegerRandomAccessIterator<uint64_t>;
auto argsRng = boost::make_iterator_range<IntTter>(0, Conditions::bigNumber);
const auto func = [](uint64_t index) {
    return Conditions::func(index);
};
auto it = std::ranges::upper_bound(transformed, searchedArg, {}, func);
...
```

Implementation of IntegerRandomAccessIterator looks like this:

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>

template <std::integral T>
class IntegerRandomAccessIterator
        : public boost::iterator_facade<
            IntegerRandomAccessIterator<T>, T,
            boost::random_access_traversal_tag, T> {
public:
    using type = IntegerRandomAccessIterator<T>;
public:
    IntegerRandomAccessIterator(T initial = 0) : _val(initial) {};
    IntegerRandomAccessIterator(const type& other) = default;
protected:
    std::ptrdiff_t
    distance_to(const type& rhs) const   { return rhs._val - _val; };
    void advance(std::ptrdiff_t n)       { _val += n; };
    T dereference() const                { return _val; };
    bool equal(const type& other) const  { return _val == other._val; };
    void increment()                     { ++_val; };
    void decrement()                     { --_val; };
public:
    T operator[](std::ptrdiff_t n) const { return _val + n; }
private:
    T _val;
private:
    friend class boost::iterators::iterator_core_access;
};

template <std::integral T>
struct std::iterator_traits<IntegerRandomAccessIterator<T>> {
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = T;
};
```

It models `std::random_access_iterator`.

Standard library solution is

```
...
auto argsRng = std::ranges::iota_view(uint64_t{0}, Conditions::bigNumber);
const auto func = [](uint64_t index) {
    return Conditions::func(index);
};
auto it = std::ranges::upper_bound(transformed, searchedArg, {}, func);
...
```

So I prefer using first variant with `IntegerRandomAccessIterator<uint64_t>` and `boost::make_iterator_range` and to remove this replacing with `std::ranges::iota_view` when ranges will finally work in `clang`.